# Jobs are not being stored in the database after add_job() has been called

Tags: python, postgresql, apscheduler

I'm trying to use **Flask-APScheduler** to run some delayed jobs and after setup and running the app it successfully creates jobs table in Postgres database but does not save jobs there after `add_job()` has been successfully called.

**config.py**
*(Tried to use default tableschema and tablename but still no jobs stored)*

```
SCHEDULER_TIMEZONE = utc
SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = False

SCHEDULER_JOBSTORES = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(
        url=SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
        tableschema=DB_SCHEMA,
        tablename='jobs'
    )
}

SCHEDULER_EXECUTORS = {
    'default': ThreadPoolExecutor(20),
    'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
}

SCHEDULER_JOB_DEFAULTS = {
    'coalesce': False,
    'max_instances': 3
}
```

**adding job piece of code**
*(Both log messages displayed and `except` body ignored. Also tried implicitly set `jobstore='default'` but still the same issue)*

```
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, DATETIME_FORMAT)

try:
    app.logger.info('adding job')
    scheduler.add_job(
        job_id,
        publish_post,
        name=job_name,
        trigger='date',
        next_run_time=date,
        kwargs={
            'channel': channel,
            'post': post
        }
    )
    app.logger.info('job added')

except Exception as e:
    app.logger.error(e)
    sentry.captureException()
    return {
        'status': 'FAILED',
        'message': 'Can not add job ({})'.format(job_name)
    }
```

**job.py**
*(Test job to run)*

```
def publish_post(channel, post):
    app.logger.info('{}: {}'.format(channel, post.text))
```

**UPD:**

With DEBUG mode on start I have the following messages:

```
gunicorn_scheduler_1    | 2019-04-04 07:07:21 - INFO     - Scheduler started
gunicorn_scheduler_1    | 2019-04-04 07:07:21 - DEBUG    - No jobs; waiting until a job is added
```

but after `add_job()` call between `adding job` & `job added` I have an additional message from APScheduler:

```
2019-04-04 07:09:46 - INFO     - Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
```

But the first message tells that scheduler is already started.

Comment: And what are the APScheduler logs?

Comment: @TomášLinhart There are no logs except mine `adding job` & `job added` going one after another. These two are the only output.

Comment: Try to set the logging level to `DEBUG`. How to do it exactly depends on your Flask logging settings and how you run the Flask app.

Comment: @TomášLinhart you are right. It added one more line to output `Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts` and I saw this message when read sources. But I start scheduler while running an app and as an evidence it create db table and this action is running also with scheduler start.

Comment: There's still couple of important pieces of information missing. What's the code you use to instantiate APScheduler? How do you start Flask app? From what I can see, I'd guess you use gunicorn and docker compose. But what's exactly the command line for gunicorn? I would say that it stems from using multiple gunicorn workers but instantiating (and starting) scheduler just once, but can't really tell. Anyway, pay attention to [this FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes) (and the one after).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved using 1 line to setup the database
Example:

```
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(jobstores=jobstores (You dont need this param), executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone='Etc/GMT+3')

scheduler = BlockingScheduler(executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, timezone='Etc/GMT+3')
```

-- Use this line to setup your database

```
scheduler.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy', url='sqlite:///jobs.sqlite')
```

Its done your jobs starting to save inside the database